# AspectJ - Avoid pointcuts calling themselves indirectly

Tags: java, aspectj

I have the following aspect:

```
public aspect MyAspect {

 before(String val): args(val, ..) &&
   call(public * execute(java.lang.String, ..)) {
     // Do something
    }
}
```

And the following classes `A` & `B`, `A` uses `B`:

```
class A() {
 public void execute(String a) {
    // Do something...
    B b = new B();
    b.execute();
 }
}

class B {
  public void execute(String a) {
     // Do something
  }
}
```

And I have a test class:

```
public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     A a = new A();
     a.execute("someVal"); // I want the aspect to be called for the first execute only
     B b = new B();
     b.execute("someVal");    
  }
}
```

- In case we call **a.execute()** I do not want the execute aspect to be caught again on `B`.
- On the other hand, when we call **b.execute() directly** from the test I do want the aspect to catch b.execute().

How can this be achieved? I tried using `cflowbelow` (with negation), but it didn't work.

**---- edit ----**

To be more precise, let's take java's `FilterChain.doFilter(..)` - filters can call other filters. I only want to catch the **first** call to doFilter (I know this can be done using `ThreadLocal` in case of fiter, but the filter is only an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do :

```
pointcut intercept_call() : call(public * execute(java.lang.String, ..));


before(String val): intercept_call() && 
                    !cflowbelow(intercept_call()) 
                     && args(val, ..)
                    {    
                        // Do something
                    }
```